# Export and import Inbound Security Rules in Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, cloud, network-security-groups, inbound-security-rule, azure-security

I've to Delete an existing `Virtual Machine` in `Azure` and the `Network Security Group` associated with the `VM`. But I need to store the `Inbound Security Rules` of the `Network Security Group` that I'm gonna Delete.

Is there any way to export the `Inbound Security Rules` as a template to some sort of `JSON`, `CSV` or any other format and then I can apply it to other `Network Security Group` by Importing the `Inbound Security Rules` from the template?

Comment: have you tried this already -- (Get-AzureNetworkSecurityGroup -Name "name" -Detailed).Rules | Export-csv -path "C:\nsgfile.csv"

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use shell, you can use a simple API call to:

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/YOUR_SUBSCRIPTIONID/resourceGroups/YOUR_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/YOUR_NSG_NAME?api-version=2016-07-01
```

This will return a JSON response with your rules under properties.securityRules.

You need to include the an Authorization header, which you can get by:

Log into Azure > open developer mode on your browser > open the network tab and look for *invoke* > copy the *Authorization header* (should start with *Bearer*).

Here is an example:

[image: How to get Azure Authorization header]

You can also use [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/azure-authorization-heade/ifmjcgakbgnpnppgijcikhpolljgdmlc) handy chrome extension to get it.